# Creating Spreadsheet from SQL using ASP - Can I attach macros?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, asp-classic

So I have been using ASP for all of a week now and perhaps this is something that I just can't do, but I am trying to dynamically generate reports from data stored in a SQL database. I am publishing the reports through an ASP document and displaying by specifying Excel for the MIME content type:

```
    Response.Buffer = TRUE
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

Is it at all possible to "attach" macros to the document? I understand I can do basic formatting in the HTML, but I would prefer to import the desired database data and handle it within excel via macros.

EDIT:
I have several reports I need to generate but for one example:

- I want to load retrieved data from the database into a sheet in excel.
- Attach Macro
- Begin Macro:

  1. Hide the specified sheet.
  2. Programatically create new sheets for categories of data.
  3. Format sheets.

The question is not about how to program the macro, just whether or not a macro can be attached and how to achieve this. In regards to alerts upon opening the sheet, if I can attach macros I should, theoretically, be able to suppress those in the Open Workbook event.

EDIT: I believe I can achieve the desired result by using OWC (Office Web Components) (see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;288130). However, I am not sure if I will be able to install it on our Web Server. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: if google spreadsheet cant do macro than i dont think this is an option but I am not sure so correct me if im wrong!

Comment: I suggest using your asp code to do whatever has to be done with the data before putting it into excel.  If you are doing this for other people, you have to remember that the default behaviour of excel is to disallow macros.

Comment: For a more full answer: what do you want to do with the data that you would rather use macros for? (edit your question to include the answer - it will help whoever else comes across this question.)

Comment: I have several reports I need to generate but for one example: I wanted to load data from the database into a sheet in excel. Begin Macro: Hide the specified sheet.  Programatically create new sheets for categories of data. Format sheets.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible in a strictly technical sense, it is neither simple nor advisable. The recipient of the sheet will get multiple prompts related to the security of your macros; the source of your macros; and if they really, truly, honestly meant to click to enable macros...